# CSS text shaking firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations

I am animating a button and I tested the animation in both Firefox and Chrome. In Chrome everything works fine, but in Firefox the text is shaking. Is there any `-moz` kind of thing I can use or something else to fix it?

It should be obvious to see when spamming clicks on it, although here in the snippet doesn't do it even on Firefox.....

EDIT: After a bit of trials and errors I found that the problem is in the text-box when I transform: translate(-50%, -50%). Do you know any alternatives? I tried a relative positioning with top 35%, but the content of the box is cut out way before

[This is what I see](https://youtu.be/QXb5T--9DQ4). The text motion changes with the zoom, but I can assure you that it changes position way after the hovering, even if it's not clear from the video.

```css
.text-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;    
    padding: 15px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

.btn:active {
    transform: translateY(-1px);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

.btn-white {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Click me</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: You're right, the snippet doesn't show any apparent shaking (I'm using Firefox). If you use Codepen can you reproduce the problem there?

Comment: increase the `animation-duration` to 1s in firefox and check it out, you can see a *shake* in the `transform` animation...

Comment: Isn't this actually an interaction issue? As you're moving the thing when you hover it, there's a chance you will move the button out from under the cursor, which leave you in an on-off loop as it repeatedly toggles the `:hover`. One nice solution would be a wrapper element that doesn't move and when hovered, applies the style to the child button.

Comment: @MarsAndBack I'm sorry, I'm not using it

Comment: @DBS it is not: the text shifts a lot later after I hover the button

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this is a *rendering* issue in Firefox - as the `animation-duration` is short, I guess you can go with the below:

Instead of `transition: all 0.2s` you can do `transition: box-shadow 0.2s, transform 0.2s` to *solve* this in Firefox - see demo below:

```css
.text-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;    
    padding: 15px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s, transform 0.2s; /* CHANGED */
}

.btn:hover {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

.btn:active {
    transform: translateY(-1px);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

.btn-white {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Click me</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, although in this way the animation is not taking place, I noticed it by increasing the time given to it, and it doesn't change

Comment: ohh ok, now I know what you mean... oops

Comment: I am sorry the animation is taking place, but clearly only for the shadow

Comment: @Johnson how about now?

Comment: @Johnson as per your edit in the question - even without the `text-box` *translate* style you have the *shaking* issue in Firefox...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187882/discussion-between-johnson-and-kukkuz).